# Code Highlighting is not working on Chrome, Big Sur

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bug, beta, big-sur

I was reading [the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), however the code was not highlighted.
(It is using highlight js to highlight the code)

OS: MacOS Big Sur public beta
Browser: Chrome(Maybe Chromium) (Not on Safari)

Screenshot:
[image]
(`println!` keyword is computed to orange in lower right)

As you can see, the code highlighting isn't working.
However, the computed color is different from black.

This is really stressing me out. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: works fine on safari and Firefox on Mojave. Try disabling extensions and also try other browsers

Comment: If it's 'really stressing' you out, you should revert back to a non-beta OS and try it again.  Beta OS's can have bugs that last throughout the beta cycle so they should only be installed on test devices and not primary devices.  Can you go back to the last supported OS and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue had also been stressing me out for months and with every Chrome or macOS update I was hoping it would get fixed… Today I stumbled upon [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100840#issuecomment-726689244) which finally helped me solve the problem!

Turns out I just had to reinstall Source Code Pro (in my case by running `brew reinstall font-source-code-pro`).